# How does the Warden know about the kids?

Tags: grimm

At the end of Season 5, Episode 3, the orphans are sent to some kind of foster care house, where The Warden:

> *woges* and commands the kids to do the same. He already knows they are *Wesen*.

How does he know that?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this will be clarified in subsequent episodes,
but it’s been indicated that Wesen can recognize each other,
even when not *woged* — perhaps by scent. 
The example that comes to mind is that, when Monroe’s parents met Rosalee,
they realized that she wasn’t a Blutbad as soon as they touched her. 
If the foster care facility is run by a Wesen,
it’s a safe bet that much/most/all of the staff are. 
Somebody in the intake/admittance process
could have detected that the children were Wesen and alerted Warden Hook.

A related question — which may have the same answer —
is how the four children got together in the first place. 
The probability of a random group of four orphans (or any other people)
all being Wesen is very low. 
They probably associated with each other because they sensed that they were similar,
even though they didn’t understand what they were.